# Electron browser window not updating when using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, electron, atom-editor

I have been looking at converting a web app to an Electron desktop app. I am starting an http server in main.js to handle ajax requests from my app.  I've created a button and defined its onclick function to call an ajax function and then update another element when the response arrives, e.g. $('#message').text('whatever').  This all works but the element ('#message') is not completely refreshed - I see the new text on top of the old text.  If I click somewhere in the window the element is refreshed properly.  I've tried calling blur() on the element and setting the focus to another element, but none of that helps.

Why does the BrowserWindow not erase the element's old text when I update it via jQuery, and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance for your help!

---

### Additional details

Here is the code that is called when the "Test" button is clicked.

```
function test_webapi() {
  var url = 'http://localhost:8888/time';
  console.log("Sending request: " + url);
  $.ajax({
    cache: false,
    method: 'GET',
    url: url,
    error: function(xhr, status, err) { console.log("Ajax error from " + url + ": " + err);  },
    success: function(data) { 
                 console.log("Have response from " + url, data);
                 $('#message').text(data.Data.Time); 
             }
  })
}
```

And the code that sets up the http server and handles the ajax request.

```
var port = 8888;
var server = http.createServer(handle_time_request);
server.listen(port, function()  {
    console.log("API server listening on port " + port);
});


function handle_time_request(req, res) {
    var tval = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
    var reply = {
        Success: true,
        Message: "whatever",
        Data: { Time: tval }
    };
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
    res.end(JSON.stringify(reply, null, 4));
}
```

Comment: Code please? It's hard to do anything for anyone when they don't provide much

Comment: Sure - see additional details above.

Comment: Using Angular to update the DOM shows the same effect (garbled text). No issues when running the page in Chrome.